# How do I turn on FollowSymLinks in Apache 2.4 run from Docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, symlink, httpd.conf

This is my first post on Stack Overflow! Long-time coder tho...

I'm trying to set up a simple web server inside a Docker container that runs PHP, is available from `http://localhost:4000`, and follows symlinks from a folder on my local drive (outside the Docker container). Everything is working great, except I can't figure out how to configure Apache to follow symlinks; I keep getting this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /testMe
on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 4000</address>
</body></html>
```

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
```

... here's how I'm building the image:

```
docker build -t sites .
```

... and here's how I'm running the container:

```
docker run -d -p 4000:80 --name sites_running -v /Users/username/Sites:/var/www/html sites
```

I've believe I've edited the `httpd.conf` file on the OSX install of Apache in the past to accomplish this—so I'm guessing I copy an `httpd.conf` file into my Docker image by placing something like this in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY ./httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

... with something like this as the contents of `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>

## was /www/webroot
<Directory "/THDL/thdl-site">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

... but of course what I've tried so far isn't working. Please help!

Comment: Where is your `/testMe` ?  Under "/THDL/thdl-site" ?  Somewhere else?  What logs do Apache show?  You could put `LogLevel debug` and try again to see what it says.

Comment: @Nic3500 `/testMe` is on an external drive symlinked from `/Users/username/Sites`—i.e., `/Users/username/Sites/testMe` is a symlink to `/Volumes/somedrive/testMe`. I haven't been able to access the Apache logs (I'm an Apache noob); I found `/var/log/apache2/error.log` after jumping into bash on the running docker container, but I can't `cat` it. Actually it looks like it's redirecting to `stderr`, I get this when I do an `ls -l` on `error.log`: `error.log -> /dev/stderr`. Not sure where I enter `LogLevel debug`... in an Apache config somewhere, or in the Docker `run` command? Tnx for the help!

Comment: In your httpd.conf, you have a directive `DocumentRoot`, which specifies what directory the web content resides.  If you ask for `http://YOURSITE/` it will fetch the files from that directory.  So to access `http://YOURSITE/testMe`, you have to have `<DOCUMENTROOT>/testMe` on the system.  Or you can use `Alias` to define that "/testMe" is located in "/Users/username/Sites/testMe".  For the logs, look in your httpd.conf.  Logs are defined there.

Comment: @Nic3500 I don't have `httpd.conf` anywhere, but I have an `apache2.conf` file. I switched `LogLevel` to `debug`, pointed `ErrorLog` to an explicit file, and added the `Indexes` option to `FollowSymLinks`. I get the same error in a browser, but here's what I get in the log, now that I can find it: `[core:error] ... AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/testMe, referer: http://localhost:4000/`. That cleared it up; the target link isn't accessible since my docker `run` command only maps the orig dir, not the smylinked dir. Relative symlinks work. Tnx!